# Prevent a randomised integer from constantly being reassigned

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small game that chooses a number at random, and then asks the user to guess it, giving indications based on the user's choice (bigger, smaller...). To generate a random number between 0 and 100, I'm using the following code:

```
int random = rand() % 101;
```

This works fine, but the only problem is that this variable is constantly being reassigned a different value. How can I prevent this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int tries;//number of tries allowed
bool win;//whether the user has won the game or not
int main(){
    string gameType;
    cout << "Please enter your game type; \"easy\", \"medium\", \"hard\", and \"expert\"." << endl;
    cin >> gameType;
    if(gameType == "easy"){
        tries = 40;
        cout << "You have 40 tries." << endl;
    }else if (gameType == "medium"){
        tries = 20;
        cout << "You have 20 tries." << endl;
    }else if (gameType == "hard"){
        tries = 10;
        cout << "You have 10 tries." << endl;
    }else if (gameType == "expert"){
        tries = 5;
        cout << "You have 5 tries.";
    }

    cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 100." << endl;

    while (win == false){
        int random = rand() % 101;//random number generation between 0 and 100
        return(random);
        bool valid = false;//if the user's number is valid (0 >= ; <= 100)
        int usedTries = 0;//the tries that the user has used up
        int selection;
        cin >> selection;
        if (selection > 100){
            cout << "Your number cannot be above 100." << endl;
            valid = false;
        }else if (selection < 0){
            cout << "Your number cannot be below 0";
            valid = false;
        }else{
            valid = true;
        }
        if (valid == true){
            if (selection > random){//bigger than target number
                cout << "Smaller!" << endl;
                usedTries = usedTries + 1;
            }else if (selection < random){//smaller than target number
                cout << "Bigger!" << endl;
                usedTries = usedTries + 1;
            }else if (selection == random){//the user has guessed the right answer
                cout << "Yay! You win!" << endl;
                win = true;
            }
            if (usedTries >= tries){//user has used up his number of tries
                cout << "Sorry, you've lost the game. Try again later." << endl;
                win = false;//to end the loop and terminate the game
            }
        }
    }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "constantly being reassigned a different value?"  Right now, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Take the assignment out of the main play loop?

Comment: ... Don't assign to it more than once? You should probably show us more code as the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: there is still people that thinks that a machine can compute a random number or in a random way ...

Comment: You need to step through your code with a debugger. Watch the value of `random` and you will see when it changes. Then think about why its changing and fix it. If you find it hard, pretend you're telling someone else what the code is doing as you step through it.

Answer (score 2):

It will only be assigned a new value when you carry out the assignment. From your description, it's being assigned inside a loop. You probably want to move the assignment out of the loop.

Typical structure would be something like:

1. call srand
2. generate random number
3. get guess from user
4. If guess is wrong, goto 3
5. If user wants to go again, goto 2

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should only be assigning it once. Either way, you can change it to this:

```
static int random = rand() % 101;
```

That will only assign it once.

Comment: It would be better to just not reassign the variable. Assign a value once and then save that value somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same consequential number and want true radom values you should use `srand` function before invoke `rand` at least one time. Pass to `srand` some random value, simple way it is pass current time in seconds etc.